# LibGDX gwt frame drop

Tags: html, gwt, libgdx

I have a problem with libgdx on gwt/html5 it drops fps every second or so even if there is nothing to render.What could be the cause of it ?

Even default project setuped for HTML5 is droping fps.

Does not matter if I build using html:superDev or html:dist same result.
[image]

EDIT:

**Found the issue:**

**Gdx.app.debug("fps: ", String.valueOf(Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond()));**

Console which shows what fps is in the games cause a big fps crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue:

**Gdx.app.debug("fps: ", String.valueOf(Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond()));**

Console which shows what fps is in the games cause a big fps crashes.